# raku typed enums not working with custom types

Tags: enums, raku, typed

Should Raku typed enums work with custom types?  I get compile errors when trying the following:

```
role A { }
class B does A { }
class C does A { }
my A enum E ( b => B, c => C );
```

results in

> Cannot find method 'mro' on object of type Perl6::Metamodel::ParametricRoleGroupHOW

and

```
class D { }
my D enum F ( b => D.new, c => D.new );
```

results in

> Cannot auto-generate a proto method for 'Int' in the setting

or does this fall under

> Complex expressions for generating key-value pairs are not supported.

**EDIT**

Regarding the first example - it looks like Raku doesn't like roles as the type constraint.  The same error is given when trying, e.g.

```
my Rational enum G ( one => 1/1, two => 1/2 );
```

and as for what I was really hoping for:

> Using a type object as a value for an enum not yet implemented. Sorry.

Comment: [This link says](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#enum) "All keys have to be of the same type". I'm no Raku expert, so I'm not certain that's the problem, but it seems likely?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is most like that only `Int` and `Str` are actually tested thoroughly.

For example, your `Rational` one wouldn't even work correctly if you had used `Rat` instead.

```raku
my Rat enum G ( one => 1/1, two => 1/2 );
say one.Rat;
# one
```

That should say `1` to be consistent with `Int` enums and `.Int`, and to `Str` enums and `.Str`

```raku
my Int enum I ( one-i => 1, two-i => 2 );
my Str enum S ( one-s => 'ONE', two-s => 'TWO' );

say one-i.Int; # 1
say one-s.Str; # ONE
```

---

So the reason for this error:

> Cannot auto-generate a proto method for 'Int' in the setting

Is that Rakudo assumes that anything other than a `Str` enum must be an `Int` enum.

What it should do is generate a method that is the same name as the class that returns a value that isn't boxed by the enum.

---

If it doesn't even work correctly for `Rat`, which compiles and is a built-in type; then a user defined one doesn't stand a chance. That applies doubly to a role.

---

### TL;DR

It is a bug. (actually at least two)